# cherrypick commits on files in a specific folder

Tags: git, merge, branch

We made a branch of `master` for a client called `master-client`. This was done to develop features specific for that client.

That branch was deployed to a test environment which the client needed to validate some of the features.

However, the features my team and I were working on were not specific for this client and were merged to master.

Now i need to cherrypick from master only commits made to files in a specific folder, eg: modules/some-module.

How do i do it? I tried getting the commits SHAs from master using `git log --pretty=format:"%H:%s << %an" .\modules\some-module\ > master-hashes.txt` and then cherrypick them one by one but the conflict resolutions were very confusing, is there an easier way?

Since my files need to be present on `master-client` exactly as on `master`, I could copy the files over and make a new commit with the eventual state of the files, but I don't know if that would cause problems in the future.

We are moving to eventually merge `master-client` back to `master` and set up flags for client specific features. Can copying the files cause problems with the eventual merge back?